# getting date from tapkulibrary

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsdate, tapku

I need to implement a calendar for my app, after searching on different libraries 
I decided that tapku was the way to go.

I'm kindda new to IOS, so this might be a newbie question:

I succesfully implemented the tapku library, and everything seems to work, except that 
I dont know how to use it.

When the user selects a date, I want the calender to give me the selected date and switch to a new viewcontroller.

How do I make this happen :)?

btw. I tried to get the documentation, but the downloadlink on github doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement the `- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)d` method of `TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate`.

```
#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate method

- (void)calendarMonthView:(TKCalendarMonthView *)monthView didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    NSLog(@"DidSelectDate %@",date);
}
```

Please download & check the sample application from this [link](http://developinginthedark.com/posts/iphone-tapku-calendar-markers)

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement the `TKCalendarMonthViewDelegate` protocol, set your object as the delegate of your `TKCalendarMonthView` and whenever the user selects a date you'll receive a `calendarMonthView:didSelectDate:` call.

If you have a look in `TKCalendarMonthView.h` you'll see all the protocol methods.